# Mapping between item created using OneNote API and item returned from OneDrive delta query

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files, microsoft-graph-onenote

I have created a NoteBook in OneDrive using OneNote API (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks)

Now when I run delta query to get changed items in OneDrive (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/delta) I can see the newly created OneNote but its ID is different.

There is no mapping between ID returned by OneNote API (after creating NoteBook) and ID returned by the delta query.

Let me know if there is any way to figure out this mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you look at the OneNote NoteBook id 1-xxxxxxxx-yyyy-zzzz-aaaa-bbbbbbbbbb it is similar to the eTag returned by OneDrive "{XXXXXXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-AAAA-BBBBBBBBBBBB},1"

Comment: Correct. Observed this but I am not sure if this is officially supported way by Microsoft. So bit hesitant to go with this.